# Understanding the importance of the QPainter in QOpenGLWidget's paintEvent function

Tags: c++, qt, opengl

In [overpaint example of qt](https://doc.qt.io/archives/4.6/opengl-overpainting.html) in paint event if I remove QPaint calls nothing is being drawed.

```
void GLWidget::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event)
{
    makeCurrent();
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glPushMatrix();

    qglClearColor(qtPurple.dark());
    glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);
    glEnable(GL_MULTISAMPLE);
    static GLfloat lightPosition[4] = { 0.5, 5.0, 7.0, 1.0 };
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, lightPosition);

    setupViewport(width(), height());

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glTranslatef(0.0, 0.0, -10.0);
    glRotatef(xRot / 16.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glRotatef(yRot / 16.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    glRotatef(zRot / 16.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);

    logo->draw();

    glShadeModel(GL_FLAT);
    glDisable(GL_CULL_FACE);
    glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glDisable(GL_LIGHTING);

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glPopMatrix();

    //QPainter painter(this); ---> I remove this and nothing
    //painter.end();               will be displayed. 
}
```

But I am curious because inside logo->draw(); there are QpenGL calls like "glDrawElements" which I believe shouldn't depend on QPainter.

What I want to understand how QPainter has an effect on this function. 
And why it does not being used when we override paintGL which can be seen in this [example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qt-opengl-hellogl-glwidget-cpp.html)

Comment: How you want then initialize Qpainter object for  void GLWidget::drawInstructions(QPainter *painter)

Comment: GLWidget::drawInstructions is just rendering a text in this example and neglectable. To reduce the amount of code I removed this part. What I exprienced is even QT Logo is not being drawn if I remove the two lines of QPainter code above.

Comment: **Note that that particular example is very old!** That's 4.6 code, released *seven years ago*! Anyhow, the solution could be very simple: have you tried adding a call to `swapBuffers`?

Answer (score 0):

When painting inside `paintEvent()` you need to call `swapBuffers()` yourself or use `QPainter`, which will call `swapBuffers()` in its destructor or in `QPainter::end()`